# Running ios and windows apps from ubuntu

Tags: windows, software-recommendation, wine

Is there any way to compile windows or ios phone apps from ubuntu ? If "yes" what kind of program should I be using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PhoneGap](http://www.kryogenix.org/days/2014/02/11/building-a-phonegap-ios-app-from-ubuntu-entirely-without-mac-os-x/) can be used for writing iOS apps on Ubuntu.